# Pip3 reset to standard configuration

Tags: python, pip

Small introduction: I'm a junior programmer, please bear with me.
I want to test some ML-code from [this](https://medium.com/emergent-future/simple-reinforcement-learning-with-tensorflow-part-0-q-learning-with-tables-and-neural-networks-d195264329d0) post.
It needs libraries such as `numpy` and `gym`.
These need to be downloaded and added to my packages.
For my understanding, since this is a company laptop, I do have root-access with sudo from my user, but I can not become root. This is relevant for me trying to installing the dependencies (mentioned libraries)
So I thought i avoid that by simply using `pip3 install --user gym`.
Problem: It returns with: User for <-Project I have been previously working on->: <-Prompts me to do something->
The python environment/infrastructure was configured for me the last time, and now I do not understand how to change that "User For" to just installing it in my local site-packages under `~` (which is `home/myusername`)

**tl;dr**: I want to create a new python project in my local directory and install the required dependencies under my user, too. Without fiddeling with the root directory. I do not know how to, since `pip3 install --user` gives me some weird user, which is not the user I am.

Edit: Here is the full error message:

```
 python3 -m virtualenv env
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/myusername/code/ML/env/bin/python3
Not overwriting existing python script /home/myusername/code/ML/env/bin/python (you must use /home/myusername/code/ML/env/bin/python3)
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command /home/myusername/code/ML/env/bin/python3 - setuptools pip wheel:
  Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://firstname.lastname:jFrog12345@companydev.jfrog.io/companydev/api/pypi/pypi/simple
Looking in links: /home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages, /home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv_support, /home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv_support
Collecting setuptools
User for companydev.jfrog.io: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/basecommand.py", line 228, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 291, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 103, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 257, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 210, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 245, in prepare_linked_requirement
    req.populate_link(finder, upgrade_allowed, require_hashes)
  File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 307, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/index.py", line 484, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/index.py", line 442, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/index.py", line 587, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/index.py", line 705, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/index.py", line 814, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 521, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/download.py", line 397, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 625, in send
    r = dispatch_hook('response', hooks, r, **kwargs)
  File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/hooks.py", line 31, in dispatch_hook
    _hook_data = hook(hook_data, **kwargs)
  File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/download.py", line 189, in handle_401
    username = six.moves.input("User for %s: " % parsed.netloc)
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2343, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 712, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 947, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 904, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 796, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /home/myusername/code/ML/env/bin/python3 - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 2
```

Comment: How is it `giving you some weird user`? If it was configured, you should find your installed packaged under `~/.local` on UNIX-like systems or `%APPDATA%\Python` on Windows.

Comment: yeah, under `~/.local` are all installed packages. But my point is when I want to install a new one, it prompts me this: `User for companydev.jfrog.io: ` meaning I have to type some user for this company..thing. I do not know why this pops up and I do not want my local repo to be connected to that.

Comment: Have you tried typing in your username? E.g. the exact same thing as command `whoami` on Linux would return.

Answer (score 0):

Within `~/.pip`, there is a `pip.conf` file.
 My weird user was written down there under a `[global]` tag, I guess that made the index look up this repository on top of the standard python repository.
 Deleting this resolved the issue.